# fPython : Making a new list from a random list of letters

Tags: python, list, random

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']#alphabet
bag_o_letters = []#letters to chose from
letter_count = [9, 2, 2, 4, 12, 2, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 2, 1, 6, 4, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]#random indexes to chose from
for x in range(26):#loops through the random index of letter_count
    for i in range(letter_count[x]):#chooses the index
        bag_o_letters.append(letters[x])#appends the index of the letter to bag_o_letters
        rack = []#list for the person to see
        for a in range(7):#makes the list 7 letters long
           rack.append(bag_o_letters.pop(random.randint(0,len(letters)-1)))#appends the letter to rack(supposedly...)
print(rack)
```

In this code that you just read it should choose random letters and put 7 of those letters in a rack that the person can see. It shows a error that I've looked over many times, but I just can't see what is wrong.

> I put comments on the side to understand the code.

**It shows this error:**

```
rack.append(bag_of_letters.pop(random.randint(0,len(letters)-1)))
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

> Can someone please help?
>
> After this code, I am going to make a input statement for the user to make a word from those letters.

Comment: `bag_o_letter` has not enough elements to handle `pop`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do but your error is caused by you trying to pop an item from bag_of_letters with a random index in the interval [0..25] (since len(letters)-1 = 25) and bag_of_letters only contains a single item in the first iteration.

Comment: First. You got some typos in there bag_o_letters & bag_o_letter.
Second: What does `i` do?

Comment: THIS IS A GAME OF SCRABBLE. So you guys can base it off that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting the *index* to `pop` for `bag_of_letters` from the length of `letters` which is obviously larger.

You should instead do:

```
rack.append(bag_of_letters.pop(random.randint(0, len(bag_of_letters)-1)))
#                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

However, there are likely to be more problems with your code. I'll suggest you use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) in one line of code or [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) on a copy of the list, and then *slice* up till index 7. Both will give you 7 randomly selected letters:

```
import random

print(random.sample(letters, 7))
# ['m', 'u', 'l', 'z', 'r', 'd', 'x']
```

---

```
import random

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
letters_copy = letters[:]
random.shuffle(letters_copy)
print(letters_copy[:7])
# ['c', 'e', 'x', 'b', 'w', 'f', 'v']
```

Comment: If I do it this way will the list stay the same all throughout the code? Also, could I replace random indexes of the rack?

Comment: Your original is not modified if you `sample`. The `shuffle` approach requires you create a copy like I did. The second Q is unclear

Comment: Using `random.sample` (or `random.shuffle` with a slice) on the unweighted list of letters will result in a skewed rack, as it's choosing from a single, linear alphabet rather than the bag of letters. You'd have an equal chance at picking a z and an s, you could only get one e, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The first time through the loop, you append one value to `bag_of_letters`, and then you try to pop an index of `random.randint(0,len(letters)-1)`. It doesn't have that many elements to pop from yet. Instead of this approach, you can make a list of the required length and sample from it:

```
letters = ['a', ...]#alphabet
letter_count = [9, ...]#random indexes to chose from
bag_of_letters = [l*c for l,c in zip(letters, letter_count)]
...
rack = random.sample(bag_o_letters, 7)
```

Comment: This answer is good, but I haven't learned `bag_of_letters = [l*c for l,c in zip(letters, letter_count)]`.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume this is for something like scrabble? Your issue is that you're choosing a random index from your list of `letters`, not `bag_o_letters`. Maybe try this:

```
rack = []
for i in range(7):
    index = random.randint(0, len(bag_o_letter) - 1)
    rack.append(bag_o_letters.pop(index))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This scrabble! Nice guess!

Comment: Ah, yes, you'll need `len(bag_o_letter) - 1`, I guess. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I uses @Moses Koledoye's answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
letter_count = [9, 2, 2, 4, 12, 2, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 2, 1, 6, 4, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]#random indexes to chose from

from random import shuffle
all_letters = list(''.join([l*c for l,c in zip(letters, letter_count)]))
shuffle(all_letters)

for i in range(int(len(all_letters)/7)):
    print all_letters[i*7:(i+1)*7]
```

Comment: Just because you saw a better answer doesn't mean you should change your own answer. You should have confidence.

Comment: Agreed. My answer was insufficient though in that it was not removing letters from the bag.

Answer (score 0):

The IndexError is expected:

> pop(...)
>       L.pop([index]) -> item -- remove and return item at index (default last).
>       Raises IndexError if list is empty or **index is out of range**.

You need to subtract 1 from the bounds of the call to `random()` after each `pop()`. Right now you are doing this:

```
l = [1,2,3]

random_idx = 2
l.pop(random_idx)
>>> l == [1,3]

random_idx = 3
l.pop(random_idx)
>>>> IndexError: pop index out of range
```

So instead, `pop()` based on `len(bag_o_letter)` rather than `len(letter)`.